# Remove pieces of a text file

Tags: list-manipulation, import, text

I have imported a text file as a Table with

```
testpbkg =  Import["unweighted_events.lhe", "Table"]
```

The file looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/xMEXvTGD).

I want just to select the text between the tag < event > and < /event > and discard the strings between < mgrwt > and < /mgrwt >.

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried importing the entire file, and then deleting everything that's not a number?

Comment: I have to keep track of < event > and  < /event > because I have to save each event in a list, like Events = {{event1},{event2},…}

Comment: Have you looked at [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/XML/tutorial/Overview.html) and it links?

Comment: Have you looked at the [String Manipulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StringManipulation.html) guide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you read the data using `Table`, you can treat it as matrix. here is your data

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
stuff = Import["tmp.txt", "Table"];
Dimensions[stuff]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it has 28 rows

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To remove these rows

```
startFrom = Flatten@Position[stuff, x_ /; x == {"<mgrwt>"}];
endAt = Flatten@Position[stuff, x_ /; x == {"</mgrwt>"}];
removeRows = Flatten[Range[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ Transpose@{startFrom, endAt}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the above are the rows we do not want

```
 rowsIwant = Complement[Range@Length@stuff, removeRows]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And the above are the ones we want to keep

```
stuff =stuff[[rowsIwant ]];
MatrixForm[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

save it back to file

```
Export["ok.txt", stuff]
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively:

```
test = Import["/home/xxxxx/Downloads/dat.dat", "Table"];
b = Position[test, "<mgrwt>"];
e = Position[test, "</mgrwt>"];
l = Partition[
   Flatten[Table[Range[b[[i, 1]], e[[i, 1]]], {i, Length[b]}]], 1];
test = Delete[test, l]// MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`StringCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringCases.html), [`StringReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html), and [`ImportString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImportString.html).

```
ImportString[#, "Table"] &@
 StringReplace[#, "<mgrwt>" ~~ Shortest[__ ..] ~~ "</mgrwt>" :> ""] & /@ 
   StringCases[testpbkg, "<event>" ~~ dat : Shortest[__ ..] ~~ "</event>" :> dat]
```

This gives a list with each event as a sublist.

Also with[`StringDelete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringDelete.html).

```
ImportString[#, "Table"] &@*
  StringDelete["<mgrwt>" ~~ Shortest[__ ..] ~~ "</mgrwt>"] /@ 
    StringCases[testpbkg, "<event>" ~~ dat : Shortest[__ ..] ~~ "</event>" :> dat]
```

Hope this helps.